# How do we know the number of s and p orbitals in a shell?

Tags: atoms, orbitals, electronic-configuration

How do we know how many s & p orbitals will be in a shell?

1. There is one 2s orbital and three 2p orbitals in shell #2.
2. There is one 3s orbital, three 3p orbitals and five 3d orbitals in
   shell #3.

Is there a reason for this? Wouldn't four 2s orbitals for shell #2 be a configuration of lower energy?

Comment: The solutions to the Schrödinger equation provides this result.

Answer (score 5):

The number of orbitals in a shell is restricted by the possible values for the quantum numbers. Those come directly from the solution of the Schrödinger Equation for the Hydrogen atom (except for the spin, but let's keep it simple here), and are applied to all other atoms as well.

The quantum numbers and their possible values are:

- the *principal quantum number* $n=1,2,3,4,5 \dots$, which relates to the period
- the *angular momentum quantum number* $l=0,1,\dots, (n-1)$ which defines the shape of the orbitals $s$, $p$, $d$ and so on
- the *magnetic quantum number* $m_l=-l,-l+1,\dots,+l$ further define the shape, e.g. $p_x$ or $d_{z^2}$
- the total spin for electrons is always $s=\frac{1}{2}$ (this may be different for other elementary particles)
- the relative spin of an electron is $m_s=-\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}$, and represents $\alpha$ and $\beta$ or up and down spin

Each electron needs to have its own unique set of quantum numbers (within one atom). This is know as Pauli Principle.

Thus for $s$ orbitals ($l=0$) there is only $m_l=0$ possible, hence there can only be one for each shell ($n$). Having four $2s$ orbitals would violate the Pauli Principle.
Additionally having a $2d$ orbital would also not be allowed as $l=2$ would be larger than $(n-1)=1$. So the $n=2$ shell is restricted to one $2s$ orbital ($m_l=0$) and three $2p$ orbitals ($m_l=-1,0,+1$).

Comment: I guess, technically, having four empty 2s orbitals wouldn't violate the Pauli principle. Having four 2s orbitals that are all populated would. IMO the Schrodinger equation argument is more fundamental than an argument based on the Pauli principle.

Comment: Technically, an orbital is defined as a *one electron wave function*, in other words the quantum mechanical description of an electron. Thus the presence of an orbital would already imply the presence of an electron. An *unoccupied* (or *virtual*) would just be *nothing* (the *vacuum state* of the electron).

Comment: Fair enough, then.